# Share Google Plus counter always shows zero

Tags: jquery, css, google-plus, google-plus-one, social-media

I'm using Sharrre script in my WordPress blog. Facebook and Twitter counter works, but Google+ counter shows always zero.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
jQuery('#googleplus').sharrre({
            share: {
                googlePlus: true
            },
            template: '<a class="box" href="#"><div class="count" href="#">{total}</div><div class="share"><i class="icon-google-plus-sign"></i></div></a>',
            enableHover: false,
            enableTracking: true,
            urlCurl: '',
            click: function(api, options){
                api.simulateClick();
                api.openPopup('googlePlus');
            }
        });
```

I'm tried to put the URL and everything possible in urlCurl: '', but it didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Where is your URL being added? I don't see any URL there. Without a URL to fetch, it would always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the:

```
href = "#"
```

section of the code. Either remove the `#` from the string (which will default to the current page) or enter the canonical path to your page.